# RUNNABLE Thread stuck in Object.notify()

Tags: java, thread-synchronization

A socket-reading thread of a network client application written in Java gets stuck in RUNNABLE state, with the stack trace pointing to `Object.notufy()`:

```
"Socket listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f6ba98b6000 nid=0x5bfb runnable [0x000000004c1e9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.yyy.ClientConnectionImpl$BulkReadOperation.consumeBuffer(ClientConnectionImpl.java:1306)
    - locked <0x00000000ee337d30> (a com.yyy.ClientConnectionImpl$BulkReadOperation)
    at com.yyy.MessageReceiver.run(MessageReceiver.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

The same stack trace is displayed each time I print it.
The relevant piece of code looks like this:

```
public void consumeBuffer (ByteBuffer buffer)
{
    if (buffer.remaining() == 0) {
        synchronized (this) {
            finished = true;
            notify ();   <<----- line 1306
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running Java 1.7.0_40.

Did anyone experience anything like this? What can cause such behavior?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible.  Perhaps your code is in an infinite loop that repeatedly calls `consumeBuffer`, and the thread stack trace just happens to show notify() because it's a slightly more expensive method and thus a more likely snapshot point than the surrounding code?